# Remove XP from XP/W7 dual boot (move boot manager)

Tags: windows-7, boot, boot-manager

Given this BCDEDIT table:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=Y:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {3e25c382-bae5-11de-a75b-e7fc07f62dc4}
displayorder            {ntldr}
                        {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 0

Windows Legacy OS Loader
------------------------
identifier              {ntldr}
device                  partition=Y:
path                    \ntldr
description             Earlier Version of Windows

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {3e25c384-bae5-11de-a75b-e7fc07f62dc4}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {3e25c382-bae5-11de-a75b-e7fc07f62dc4}
nx                      OptIn
```

What should I do to remove the XP installation on Y: and completely remove that partition's dependency on booting, move the boot manager to C: and mark C: active (System) so I can boot from it?

The "guides" I've found are a bit contradictory and some use bcdedit, some use bcdboot and some a manual thing with bootrec /fixmbr + bootrec /fixboot triage.

---

I am going to answer this myself somewhat.

I ended up doing this:

• copied Y:\Boot\* to C:\Boot. Some files could not be copied. I expected this, and the next step should take care of it.

• exported system store

```
bcdedit /export C:\Boot\BCD
```

• changed Windows Boot Manager location

```
bcdedit /store C:\Boot\BCD /set {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795} device partition=C:
```

• changed Windows Memory Tester location

```
bcdedit /store C:\Boot\BCD /set {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d} device partition=C:
```

• changed Windows Legacy OS Loader location

```
bcdedit /store C:\Boot\BCD /set {466f5a88-0af2-4f76-9038-095b170dc21c} device partition=C:
```

• updated master boot code

```
Windows_7_DVD:\BOOT\BOOTSECT /NT60 C: /FORCE
```

• changed the active partition

```
DISKPART
  select disk 0
  select partition 1
  active
```

However, it didn't work anyway. I had to do a repair because "BOOTMGR is missing". I believe I should have also copied **bootmgr** from Y: to C:, but I'm not sure if that was all I missed.

I'm still curious if this is a really bass-ackwards way of doing this process, and I would very much want to know where I went wrong.

Thanks for all the contributions.

Comment: I'm in this hell right now too.  Eagerly waiting to see if someone can answer it...

Answer (score 2):

If you install EasyBCD it gives you a nice user interface to editing the BCD.

Get it [here](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) . It's free too.

Answer (score 0):

the best thing to do is first to log into the account u want to remove then take the necesssary backup from that drive (My Doc, My Pic, My Fav, etc etc.)

then restart and log into the other O.S. then select the drive in which the other O.S. to be removed is installed Right click and format

then restart

u will notice that the boot option still exists

for that log into the existing o.s. go to RUN on the start menu else type "Windows + R"

a small screen comes up now write "msconfig"

there seleact the BOOT tab Make the current os as default and delete the other one.

now if asked select not to show the warning again. Restart

there u go the un wanted os has been safely removed..............

Enjoy ............!!!!!!!!!!!! WARICK

Comment: That won't work painlessly I'm afraid. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on My Computer>Properties>Advanced>Startup & Recovery>First remove the row which includes XP,then format the disk which includes XP.It should be OK.

Comment: This won't work either, unless you do a repair afterwards. Thanks though.